# VMWare Operations Manager (vCOPS) custom dashboard without logging in

Tags: vmware-vsphere, vmware-vcenter

1, How could I set up vCOPS so it does not require users to log in by default?

2, How can I actually design a custom dashboard? I looked at the "custom UI" document from vmware, it tells what can be customized but doesn't tell the how.

Comment: If you access vCOPS from the vCenter Web Access, the authentication is passed-through.

Comment: yes, I know. but I want to users to just be able to go to https://stats.blahblah/ and have the vCOPS dashboard there.

Answer (score 1):

This should be possible. You can take a look at the the online API documentation embedded in the web server. The [**Custom UI Administration Guide**](http://www.vmware.com/pdf/vcops-57-custom-ui-admin-guide.pdf) may help, too.

Go to: https://ip.of.vcops/HttpPostAdapter/OpenAPIServlet and enter your admin credentials. There's some basic API info available there...

[image]